# How to Add Cookies to my COUNTDOWN Timer based on Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, countdown

Well Finally i code the script which countdown and repeat itself but now i want to add cookie functionality there so that it won't start again by refresh the page or leaving the page,

Here's the link - http://soniprojects.org/timer/

Comment: Share the code, fiddle would be good.

Comment: You can directly see it online sir, its just a HTML based code.. 
There is one HTML File, One CSS and One JS file..